# Camera view blocked detection using opencv in python3 windows platform

Tags: python, opencv, detection

I am developing a camera state monitoring service using opencv in Python3, am facing a problem in detecting if a camera view is blocked by an obstruction (obstacle) ,like a tree or any object blocking the view, how can i detect such case using opencv in Windows platform

Comment: You need to reformat your question. What have you tried so far? Is there any code we can look at? What kind of scene is your camera looking at, or should it be general? etc

Comment: My scene will be a road with cars crossing, it is a camera monitoring the streets. I have a baseline image to compare to , which was generated from a video after removing moving objects, and each day will take a snapshot at the same time of the baseline image by the same logic.
There is no code to work with, am trying to find some logic to work with , how to say that there is a blocking object in the view, or even if lot of dust on the lens that is blocking the view.

Comment: I thought in comparing the features of both images, but if am still getting more cars in the frame due to huge traffic then this wont work, because I need to limit the time of the video taken to generate the video, considering the no of cameras am dealing with

Comment: You should look into block-matching, sometimes reffered to as template-matching. It essentially breaks the image up into smaller blocks and compares the individual elements, perhaps this can be utilised for your problem. Goodluck.

Answer (score 0):

if something got stuck on the camera, then optical flow in that area will be very less and you can say that it is blocked.